# Updating Fragment UI from within the parent activity

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, fragment

I am noticing a bizarre behavior when I am trying to update some of the fragment UI elements from within the parent activity.

If somebody can provide some reasoning behind it, I would really appreciate it!

Here's the scenario:

I have an Activity... say MyActivity. **Inside MyActivity** I have a couple of fragments: **LeftFragment** and **RightFragment**. The LeftFragment has a button: "**showTheDialogBtn**". When **I press "showTheDialogBtn"** I get a dialog with some EditText fields and another **button OK** in the end. The dialog is being **created within the MyActivity** (e.g. not inside the LeftFragment). Now, when I **press on OK** button located on that dialog, I am trying to change the text color located on the RightFragment by calling instance of **rightFragment.changeMyTextFieldColor(RED)**.

What I am noticing is that **calling the changeMyTextFieldColor on an instance of the RightFragment doesn't do anything**. However, if I get the TextView that I need to change right inside the MyActivity (inside the onClickListener of OK button), then everything seems to work fine.

Does it make any sense to anyone? Please, let me know.

Comment: Are you sure the instance of the `RightFragment` that you have is actually the one that is being displayed?

Comment: I believe it is. But I'll double check. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the isVisible method returns true on the RightFragment.

Comment: Hm, can't think of anything else without looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't change is because you call  `changeMyTextFieldColor` that is not related to `ONCREATEVIEW()`. 
More detail: What you see on screen comes from onCreateView(). So if you want to update the UI, you should modify the view that comes from onCreateView(). You should:

1. Make sure that the Context of the view come from onCreateView() and the Context of 'changeMyTextFieldColor' are identical.
2. Make sure that you change the color of the component that actually belong to the 'view' generated from onCreateView(). For example: save the view of onCreateView() for later modification.